# Comic about two species with declining populations living on an alien world

Tags: story-identification, comics, aliens

The first time I read this comic was on the ComiXology app back in 2009/2010. I only read the free preview, so I never got to know the ending of this comic. But, here are some details that I remember:

- There are two species in the alien world. One species lives on land and the other lives in the sea. The species living in the sea reminds me of sea monkeys (pointy things on the head). All the characters are a blue-ish/green-ish colour.
- One species is mostly female and the other species is mostly male because of reproduction. If I remember correctly, the female's head exploded after giving birth in one species and the male has to cut his heart out for child reproduction in the other species. This is why children from both species have to grow up without a mom or dad.
- The two species have multiple wars with each other on a beach to take out their frustration and losses. This has caused their population to decline even further, beyond the deaths associated with reproduction.
- The protagonist is a little blue/green alien boy (looks like Baby Groot). He talks about how his species and the other species are slowly declining, but he is still looking for hope.

I've tried searching for this comic by going back to my ComiXology account, but it's no longer there! Any suggestions is appreciated.